# Why have I to put this .properties file outside my project?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, properties, jar, architecture

I am developing a command line application in Java (so it is executed into the shell and not run into an application server).

This application perform some queries on a database. My boss say to me that I have to put the server information (URL, username and password) into a **.properties** file. Ok I think that untill now this is a pretty standard thing.

He say to me that I have not to put this **.properties** file into my project (for example into the **src** folder) but this file have to be external to the project and form my application I have to access to it.

I have some difficulties to understand why. The only reason that I can imagine is that if some data change (for example the DB URL or the user credential) the final user can change it easilly without have access to the final .jar file.

According to your opinion this is a classical best practice? Are there some other reason to do it?

Tnx

Comment: Maybe you should ask your boss? He's the only one who definitely knows his reasoning...

Comment: We do this at my job. This is so that sensitive information is not saved into the project and instead on the server itself. That way, the database connections, etc can be locked down and only the application can read from it. When you deploy, the properties file will be in the proper location and just pull from there. And also, each server may have it's own configuration so you don't need to change & recompile or make special code changes to check which server you're on. It just pulls the information.

Comment: Some properties could change during project life. So, it could be better edit them when they're stored into file which is accessible without have to unzip a jar file.

Comment: @cigno5.5 - The OP isn't asking about why the use of a properties file, but why is it external to the project

Comment: @Ascalonian in fact I said that a reason could be to have the ability of edit properties outside jar (that would means without change anything inside project nor unzip a distribution file)

Comment: My bad, read the comment wrong haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.properties file is  mainly used  to store the configurable parameters of an application to ensure the configurable changing parameters don't get coupled with the source code. Also this ensures that, the configurable parameters of your application stays at one place.

For example, if you want to make changes in the server information you just have to make the changes in .properties file and your source code will read it from .properties file.

It is a really good practice to separate the changing parts of your source code from static parts.

Comment: This doesn't answer about why putting it external to the project

Comment: Putting external to the project ensures it doesn't get coupled with the source code in src. Also, putting the configuration separate allows different projects to reuse the configuration, if needed.